# How to convert byte to the same string in Java

Tags: java

I try to convert byte to the same string.
Such as below:

```
byte b = (byte)0xAA;
```

Then, convert byte b to the same string as below:

```
String s = "AA";
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm very curious what the actual end-goal is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

byte b = (byte)0xAB;
String s = String.format("%x", b);

Comment: At least one got it right, this was getting kind of embarrassing there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Byte` class? It has `toString()` methods you can use.

Comment: But the method convert byte 0xaa to "-86"

Answer (score 0):

Byte.toString(b) will print String representation of String for specified byte 'b'